# scala implementing two interfaces with a same method name

Tags: java, scala

Say I have the following two interfaces defined in java:

```
public interface A
{
  public void test();
}

public interface B
{
  public void test();
}
```

Then can I define a single scala class to implement both interfaces?

```
class C extends A with B {


}
```

How to define both `test()` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to implement both methods, you either need to have different method names, different method parameter lists, or different classes. Choose 1 of the 3 options. This is true in both Scala and Java.

(Well, technically you could use some form of metaprogramming, but you probably don't want to.)

Answer (score 0):

You can define this class, but it will have only one implementation of the function test(). This can be useful in situations where both interfaces have something quite common, such as getName() or getTimestamp(). The name or timestamp relates to the object that is created, and not to the interface implementation.

Comment: But I need to implement both interface methods in this instance.

Comment: Here's some more: 
http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/117.html
http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/05/30/traits-how-scala-tames-multiple-inheritance/

Comment: What does it mean to have two implementations of a single method signature? It's just not possible.

Comment: Yes I guess that is the question. I have a case of two Java interfaces that happen to have the same method name and I have a single scala class that wants to implement both. Was wondering if there was some sort of syntax to achive this. eg. `override def A.test()` and `override def B.test()` for example. But as you say it may not be possible.

Comment: @RandallSchulz For what it's worth - if you build the language feature, it is possible. See [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx) which has `new` allowing you to hide other methods, and then implement the interface method explicitly. Depending on what type you use the class as, you use the appropriate method. (e.g: `((A) obj).test()` will do one thing, `((B) obj).test()` will do another) where the type of `obj` implements `A` and `B`.